# How to notate a vector out of a $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: notation

Say you have a set $\mathbb{R}^+$, (in other words the positive real numbers), how can one express a vector with $n$ elements out of it?

$\mathbb{R}^{+n}$ might by confusing and $\mathbb{R}^{n+}$ as well.

Is there a quite accepted notation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use $\mathbb R^+$ for the set of positive real numbers, then you can use $(\mathbb R^+)^n$ for the corresponding set of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

A different way to express $\mathbb{R}^+$ is $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, which

1. removes any potential ambiguity about wheterh $0$ is included, and
2. allows an exponent to be added without using parentheses.

So my preference would be $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}^n$.